# Proxy server written in Dart returns HTML instead of web page

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy

I'm working on a proxy server written in Dart and while it forwards GET requests fine, in the browser they're rendered as HTML instead of the actual web page.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

void launchProxy() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080);
  await server.forEach((HttpRequest request) async {
    // Parse headers
    final headers = <String, String>{};
    request.headers.forEach((name, values) {
      // Clean up request headers
      String headerValue = values.toString();
      headerValue = headerValue.replaceAll('[', '');
      headerValue = headerValue.replaceAll(']', '');
      // Add the header to the full set of headers
      headers.putIfAbsent(name, () => headerValue);
    });
    //headers.putIfAbsent('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', () => '*');
    // Handle GET request
    if (request.method == 'GET') {
      final response = await http.get(request.uri, headers: headers);
      request.response.write(response.body);
      request.response.close();
    }
    // Handle POST
    else if (request.method == 'POST') {
      // Get the body from the io.HttpRequest
      final bodyBytes = await request.first;
      final response =
          await http.post(request.uri, headers: headers, body: bodyBytes);
      request.response.write(response.body);
      request.response.close();
    }
    // Handle PUT
    // Handle HEAD
    // Handle OPTIONS
    // Handle TRACE
    // Handle DELETE
  });
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the view I'm seeing in my browser:
[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGORv.png)

I've tried a number of different things and this is the furthest I can get with it so now I'm asking for help. I'm not a software engineer by trade, just tinkering for my own ammusement.

Comment: Why aren't you just using shelf, including the shelf_proxy plugin?  Or is it just for your own challenge?

Comment: shelf_proxy, from what I can see, only supports GET requests. I never saw a way to add a request body to it. Also, I need to be able to proxy multiple different requests and from what I can tell, shelf_proxy only does one proxy request to whatever URL you pass it when first created. I'd have to tear down the proxy and re-create it on every new request then.

Comment: What you want isn't a proxy then.  How would you be communicating to indicate how to proxy each request, if not within that request?  Also, it looks like shelf_proxy works with all kinds of http requests, not just GET.

Comment: "in the browser they're rendered as HTML instead of the actual web page." Uh, a web page *is* HTML. Looking at your screenshot, your problem is that the HTML is treated as plaintext. You're copying just the HTTP response body but are ignoring the response's headers. One of those headers is [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), which tells the browser whether to interpret the response body as raw text or whether to render it as HTML.

Comment: Well seeing as I'm not in grade school I am aware that web pages are HTML (among other things). I haven't found a way to pass the headers all the way through to tell the browser how to render that which seems to be the problem.

Comment: You can't do `request.responseHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'text/html';`? (Or really you'd want to iterate over the entries in `response.headers` and copy each one.)

Comment: And that was really close to the solution:

`request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;`

I think I'll have to write a function to extract the original content type and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

And the solution:

```
// Handle GET request
    if (request.method == 'GET') {
      final response = await http.get(request.uri, headers: headers);
      // This renders the page correctly
      request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.parse(response.headers['content-type']!);
      // Need to write a function to iterate over all headers and transfer them
      request.response.write(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      request.response.close();
    }
```

I think I'll have to write a function to extract the original content type and apply it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).